# Changing a div that contains a view link

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I've written some code to load a section of my application between views. While my code works, I'm wondering if there is a better way to do it. (partial views perhaps?) I currently load the views, then show/hide them depending on a button click.

```
<div id="wrapper">

@*Sidebar*@
@Html.Partial("_AdministrationSidebar")


@*PAGE CONTENT*@
<div id="page-content-wrapper">

<div id="manage" style="clear: both;"></div>

<div id="edit" style="clear: both;"></div>

<div id="create" style="clear: both;"></div>


</div>@*page-content-wrapper*@
</div>@*wrapper End*@


<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#manage").load("RolesAdmin/Manage/");

});

function editItem(Id) {
   $("#edit").load("RolesAdmin/Edit/" + Id);
   $("#manage").hide();
   $("#edit").show();
}

function createItem(Id) {
   $("#create").load("RolesAdmin/Create/" + Id);
   $("#manage").hide();
   $("#create").show();
}

function manageItem() {
   $("#manage").show();
   $("#create").hide();
   $("#edit").hide();
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a nice simple approach to an SPA. I assume you are returning partial pages from your actions.

A slight improvement would be to hide all pages before showing. This way you don't have to touch the other functions when adding a new page.

Add a class to the page divs, like class='partial-page'. Then in your show page function:

```
function createItem(Id) {
   $(".partial-page").hide();
   $("#create").load("RolesAdmin/Create/" + Id);
}
```

You could also make things more generic and allow for a query string. e.g.

```
function showPage(url, param){
   $(".partial-page").hide();
   if ($.isPlainObject(param) {
     $("#create").load(url + '?' + $.param(param));
   }
   else {
     $("#create").load(url + '/' + param);
   }
}

function createItem(Id) {
   showPage("RolesAdmin/Create", id)
}

function showSomeOtherPage(id, name) {
   // RolesAdmin/SomeOtherPage?id=123&name=freddy
   showPage("RolesAdmin/SomeOtherPage", {id:id, name:name})
}
```

Further, you can support the back button by using jquery.history.js